# Как обернуть последнее слово в html-тег с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

Имеется массив с заголовками статей. Как обернуть последнее слово строки в тег `<span>`.
Например, из `Заголовок номер один`, `Заголовок номер два`, `Заголовок номер три`, получилось:
`Заголовок номер <span>один</span>`, `Заголовок номер <span>два</span>`, `Заголовок номер <span>три</span>`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce6bb4136487e84a88ce8146a5acc377c984edf2)

```
<?php

$subject = 'Заголовок номер один';

$explode = explode(' ', $subject);
$last_index = count($explode) - 1;
$explode[$last_index] = "<span>{$explode[$last_index]}</span>";

print_r(implode(' ', $explode));
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуй, я в PHP особо не силён, но сделать это действительно просто, я приведу алгоритм + код на JS, Я думаю ты сможешь его переписать.

1. Первым делом тебе нужно запустить цикл по перебору всех заголовков в массиве.
2. Далее разделяешь строку по пробелам, у тебя получается массив массивов, т.е.:
   [['Заголовок', 'номер', 'два'], etc..]
3. Выбираешь последний элемент массива и добавляешь ему спереди , а после него

   let arr = ['Заголовок номер раз', 'Заголовок номер два'];
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   let splitHeader = arr[i].split(' ');
   splitHeader[arr.length - 1] = '' + splitHeader[arr.length - 1] + '';
   arr[i] = splitHeader.join(' ');
   }